# Flutter how do I position this text and icon in a row?

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble aligning my text and my icons.
Here's what my output looks like: [image: Text and Icon]

I wanted the text to be in the middle left side of the icons.
I've tried adding margins and padding. But the icons just wont align with the text, I even tried placing the icons in a different widget.

Here's my code:

```
 Widget buildFollowText() {
return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 5,
      top: 5,
    ),
    child: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 0,
          right: 250,
        ),
        child: Text(
          'or follow us on:',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "DMSans",
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            letterSpacing: -0.3,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 30.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          right: 70,
          bottom: 10,
        ),
        child: buildIcons(),
      )
    ])));
  }

Widget buildIcons() {
return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 0,
    ),
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.facebook,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0, left: 40),
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.twitter,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 50,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the padding.
2. set mainAxisAlignment center for the column.
3. Wrap the Text('or follow us on') with Row() and set mainAxisAlignment.center.

Follow this code.

Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
left: 5,
top: 5,
),
child: Container(
width: double.infinity,
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Text(
'or follow us on:',
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: "DMSans",
fontSize: 15,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
letterSpacing: -0.3,
color: Colors.grey,
),
),
],
),
Container(
width: 50,
height: 30.0,
margin: EdgeInsets.only(
right: 70,
bottom: 10,
),
child: buildIcons(),
)
],
),
),
),

Comment: This code centered both the text and Icon

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      // text container
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text('or follow us on:'),
      ),
      // icon container
      Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.face,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 30,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.transfer_within_a_station_rounded,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 30,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Already tried doing so, the output is still the same

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen shot of current code output]

```
 Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // text container
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('or follow us on:'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  // icon container
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.face,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.transfer_within_a_station_rounded,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 30,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```